# Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: mesh

I keep receiving this:
Is it normal or i missed something?

```
- ready started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
- event compiled client and server successfully in 1247 ms (18 modules)
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 254 ms (18 modules)
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- warn ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js
./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib.js
./node_modules/@meshsdk/core/dist/core.js
./node_modules/@meshsdk/react/dist/react.js
- warn Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
- warn ./node_modules/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser/cardano_serialization_lib_bg.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

node versions LTS 18 and 16
Win/Ubuntu 20/22

url: https://meshjs.dev/guides/nextjs

It seems to be working fine, but how can I get rid off?
It installs @meshsdk/core 1.5.2 but can't upgrade to 1.5.4 due to @meshsdk/react@1.1.7

Thanks in advance!